# How to split a row into multiple rows with a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This:

```
column_A|column_B|column_C
a|a,b,c|b
b|a|b
c|a|c
```

should end up like this:

```
column_A|column_B|column_C
a|a|b
a|b|b
a|c|b
b|a|b
c|a|c
```

column_B has CSV like data. columns are seperated by an arbitrary character in this case a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the combination of `string_to_array` and `unnest`:

```
SELECT column_a, unnest(string_to_array(column_b,',')), column_c 
FROM   tablename;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4101e/2)

That said, you did not give enough information about the datatype and an *arbitrary character* is never arbitrary if it is acting as a delimiter.