# Postgresql Split single row to multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. I'm getting below results from a query and now I need to split single row to obtain multiple rows. 
I have gone through below links, but still couldn't manage it. Please help.
[unpivot and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql)
[How to split a row into multiple rows with a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919329/how-to-split-a-row-into-multiple-rows-with-a-single-query)

**Current result**

```
id,name,sub1code,sub1level,sub1hrs,sub2code,sub2level,sub2hrs,sub3code,sub3level,sub3hrs --continue till sub15

1,Silva,CHIN,L1,12,MATH,L2,20,AGRW,L2,35

2,Perera,MATH,L3,30,ENGL,L1,10,CHIN,L2,50
```

**What we want**

```
id,name,subcode,sublevel,subhrs

1,Silva,CHIN,L1,12

1,Silva,MATH,L2,20

1,Silva,AGRW,L2,35

2,Perera,MATH,L3,30

2,Perera,ENGL,L1,10

2,Perera,CHIN,L2,50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use union:

```
select id, 1 as "#", name, sub1code, sub1level, sub1hrs
from a_table
union all
select id, 2 as "#", name, sub2code, sub2level, sub2hrs
from a_table
union all
select id, 3 as "#", name, sub3code, sub3level, sub3hrs
from a_table
order by 1, 2;

 id | # |  name  | sub1code | sub1level | sub1hrs 
----+---+--------+----------+-----------+---------
  1 | 1 | Silva  | CHIN     | L1        |      12
  1 | 2 | Silva  | MATH     | L2        |      20
  1 | 3 | Silva  | AGRW     | L2        |      35
  2 | 1 | Perera | MATH     | L3        |      30
  2 | 2 | Perera | ENGL     | L1        |      10
  2 | 3 | Perera | CHIN     | L2        |      50
(6 rows)
```

The `#` column is not necessary if you want to get the result sorted by `subcode` or `sublevel`.

You should consider normalization of the model by splitting the data into two tables, e.g.:

```
create table students (
    id int primary key, 
    name text);

create table hours (
    id int primary key, 
    student_id int references students(id),
    code text, 
    level text, 
    hrs int);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help given. This is working fine with using "union all". And thanks for table normalization tip as well. Unfortunately we can not change table structure now.

Comment: Yes, `union all` makes sense, I've added this for a future reader.